# Installing and running ssh server from bash script

Tags: openssh

I want to be able to install `openSSH` package and enable and disable it from the script.

I have tried doing it like this:

```
elif [[ $1 = "-ss" ]]; then
    echo "Manage SSH Server"
    apt-get install openssh-server
elif [[ $1 = "-ssEnable" ]]; then
    systemctl enable ssh
    systemctl start ssh
```

but when I try to install it, it says:

```
dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

Comment: Make sure to add the `-y` flag

Answer (score 0):

This happens when some packages got somehow broken. Possibly some previous installation was interrupted.

As the message says, running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` or `apt-get -f install` should fix it.

Comment: So do I change the script to that? It has to work on multiple computers, not just mine.

Comment: No, that should be a one time thing. That's probably related to some previous installation of yours. Should be unrelated to the script you're working on ...